# Lua http request hangs

Tags: http, lua, request

I am calling  lua http.request with timeout. before i make http request if network is down i will get http  status as network unreachable but if network is not available after Http request it just hangs. is there any way to handle this issue.

```
local isHttps = string.match(type(url) == "table" and url.url or url, "^https:") 
local http = isHttps and require("ssl.https") or require("socket.http")
local r,s,h 
if isHttps then 
    http.TIMEOUT = 300 
    r,s,h = http.request ({
        url = url,
        method = "GET",
        sink = ltn12.sink.table(results),
        headers= ["Cache-Control"] 
        = "no-cache"["X-Token"]=config.token
    })
```

Comment: Please show your code? Which library are you using?

Comment: local isHttps = string.match(type(url) == "table" and url.url or url, "^https:")
local http = isHttps and require("ssl.https") or require("socket.http")
local r,s,h if isHttps then http.TIMEOUT = 300 r,s,h = http.request ({url = url,method = "GET",sink = ltn12.sink.table(results),headers= ["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"["X-Token"]=config.token})

Comment: Click _edit_ in your question; and then add the code to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In future please format your code so people can read it. I have done it for you this time, please check that it is still OK. Also you'll notice the last key is incorrect syntax please fix.

Comment: Did you wait more than the 5 minute timeout you have set?